# NEST filtering source and creating instances of object using object constructor

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I'm having an issue with source filtering in NEST client.

This is my code sample:

```
var searchRequest = client.Search<Report>(analysisDescriptor
  .Source(s => s
    .Includes(i => i
      .Fields(
        f => f.ReportId,
        f => f.Abstract,
        f => f.Title
      )
    )
  )
  .Size(10));
```

Where `analysisDescriptor` is `new SearchDescriptor<Report>()` with business logic for text search.

This is my class with constructor:

```
public class Report
{
  public Report(int reportId, string itemAbstract, string title)
  {
    Abstract = itemAbstract;
    ReportId = reportId;
    Title = title;
    /* Other fields */
  }

  public int ReportId { get; }
  public string Abstract { get; }
  public string Title { get; }
  /* Other fields */
}
```

Now the issue is that tech leads don't want to have `set` properties and want to have a constructor instead.

The code above *almost* works:

1. ReportId is assigned
2. Title is assigned

The issue is that `Abstract` field is not assigned because constructor has it declared as `itemAbstract`. This has been done because `abstract` is a reserved keyword in C#. If I change field name in constructor to `@abstract` - this works, but doesn't seem right because I have to use reserved keyword.

Changing `Abstract` to `ItemAbstract` doesn't seem like an option because we have it like that in database and that would require even more changes.

So ideally I'm looking for a way to pass `Abstract` field from my `searchRequest` into `Report` constructor as `itemAbstract`. Hopefully that makes sense.

I'm open to any other solution that is clean and makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work since NEST just uses Json.net for serialization.

```
public Report(int reportId,[JsonProperty("abstract")]string itemAbstract, string title)
  {
    Abstract = itemAbstract;
    ReportId = reportId;
    Title = title;
    /* Other fields */
  }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!